When I try to add Index for firestore, the collection Id is in arabic and it is created but, the collection turn into this %D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%83
all collections Ids are like so
Before it was normal to add indexes in arabic, but i started to create these indexes after a while of creating the application and got this error.
I have tried to create indexes in english and it was created but it is not expressing the real collections

As far as I can see the index is created. Does it work the way you want?
